# Creating a .txt file with VBA. How do you create variable spaced columns?

Tags: excel, vba, compilation, formatting, notepad

I have managed to use piece of code which will export data from an Excel spreadsheet and into a .txt document.

Due to the nature of the task however the data has to be certain spaces wide, i.e the first column in the .txt folder has to be 8 spaces wide, second column 20, etc. I know how to create fixed length columns whilst importing to a .txt using VBA (as below), but how is variable spacing done.

Code so far is as follows:

```
    Public Sub CompileMacro()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strRow As String
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim fs As FileSystemObject


    Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(" C: . . . ", True, False)

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    Row = 1
    Do While Row <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

       strRow = ""

       Col = 1
       Do While Col <= ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
           strRow = strRow & ws.Cells(Row, Col) & PadSpace(8, Len(ws.Cells(Row, Col)))
    
           Col = Col + 1

       Loop

       ts.WriteLine strRow

       Row = Row + 1
       ws.Range("A" & Row).Activate
    Loop

    ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

    End Sub



    Public Function PadSpace(nMaxSpace As Integer, nNumSpace As Integer) As String
       If nMaxSpace < nNumSpace Then
           PadSpace = ""
       Else
           PadSpace = Space(nMaxSpace - nNumSpace)
       End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to hold your padding settings:

```
padding = Array(8, 20, 10, 10, 20, 8, 10, 10)
```

Change your string-builder to use the value for the given column:

```
strRow = strRow & ws.Cells(Row, Col) & PadSpace(padding(Col - 1), Len(ws.Cells(Row, Col)))
```

So you're loop would look something like this:

```
Row = 1

padding = Array(8, 20, 10, 10, 20, 8, 10, 10)

Do While Row <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

   strRow = ""

   Col = 1
   Do While Col <= ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
       strRow = strRow & ws.Cells(Row, Col) & PadSpace(padding(Col - 1), Len(ws.Cells(Row, Col)))

       Col = Col + 1

   Loop

   ts.WriteLine strRow

   Row = Row + 1
   ws.Range("A" & Row).Activate
   
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using Space$ in combination with unusual Mid$ on the left of assignment operator like the following

```
strRow = Space$(padding(col))
Mid$(strRow, 1, Len(ws.Cells(Row, col))) = ws.Cells(Row, col)
```

Also, you need padding array for example defined like `padding = Array(0, 8, 20)` .

`Mid$(strRow, 1, Len(ws.Cells(Row, col)))` rewrites space characters inside strRow string with `ws.Cells(Row, col)`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in the past using the Excel feature `Save As .prn`. This "text printer" will preserve the spacing from the sheet so you will have to adjust the column width until it comes out perfect. If you are setting your column widths with VBA already then it's simple.

You can call this from VBA on a per-sheet basis. Looks like this:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
ws.SaveAs fileName, xlTextPrinter
```